# container won't extend to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i'm extremely frustrated right now. I can't figure out why my container won't extend to the bottom of the page. it reaches the bottom of the visible window, but if you scroll down past that, then the background ends.

my basic structure looks something like this...

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        /*Some Content here but all divs opened here are closed. (Title Bar, Nav, etc)
        <div id='mainTableContainer'>
             /*This is where a bulk of the code is. A table is generated in PHP and it
                gets fairly lengthy.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So that's basically the HTML. I can't for the life of my figure out why #container won't 
extend to the bottom of the page!

And the CSS

```
html{
height:100%;    
}
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 "Museo-sans", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(images/bg.png);
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #FFF;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left-style:dashed;
    border-right-style:dashed;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#bf0000;

  }
 .content {
    height:100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
#mainTableContainer{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
```

}

I tried a lot of the tips I found on this site, but nothing was helping. I don't think anything is floated. I tried setting all the heights to 100%, I tried setting a min width... I can't figure it out!!

EDIT:
OK I MADE A JSFILDDLE
So if you shrink the size of the display second in jsfiddle to smaller than the table, and then refresh it, you'll see that the background doesn't go all the way down, and the table is left 'floating' in the air.
http://jsfiddle.net/LGM3y/1/

Comment: Consider reproducing the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to select a class, but container is an ID, so you need:

```
#container
```

instead of

```
.container
```

If that doesn't fix it try setting the background CSS on the HTML tag instead of the container.

```
html{
    height:100%;    
    background:#ccc url(images/bg.png);
}
```

etc

Comment: Don't forget to change the container to min-height: 100% so its background extends off the page if content activates a vertical scroll.

Comment: oops, sorry about the class/id confusion. that's not it. i typed the html but cut pasted the css so i missed that. theyre the same in my code

Comment: Ah sorry! Try the HTML thing so :)

Comment: the html thing produces an even worse result. i'm trying to have a single column layout, with white in the center 960px and grey on the sides. but the white won't extend to the bottom...

Comment: Hmmm... Try removing the top and bottom padding from .content and putting it on the container or the body.

Otherwise we might need a jsfiddle to help any further, sorry!

Comment: Remove the height setting on container. Works for me :)                  

    .container {
     /*height:100%;*/
    }

http://jsfiddle.net/LGM3y/8/

Comment: yeah! that seems to work. thanks a lot i can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: It's always something simple haha, glad to help, best of luck and thanks for the rep :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine (if I understand exactly what you're asking) if you remove the

```
html {height: 100%;}
```

The container fills the space ..

Answer (score 0):

One trick I use for this on `<div>`'s (which has mixed results in IE) is to specifically set `display: block` in the CSS rules for the container that you want to extend.

Example:

```
#container {
display: block;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yep it's worth trying this too!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U4aWc/

Made you a fiddle :) Tweak it around if it's not right and see if we can help then!

Comment: i made a jsfiddle that show's my problem. check my original post.

Comment: Sorry dude, half asleep, will check it out now :)